# Span Wallpaper Across Displays in Lockscreen

Tags: lightdm, desktop-background

In the Appearance tool, we have the option to span a wallpaper across multiple displays.

On the Desktop it works fine:

[image: Screenshot of spanned image on desktop]

However, on the lock screen I see the same image repeated three times:

[image: Screenshot of lockscreen]

How do I span the wallpaper across displays on the lock screen? I don't see any option to do so in the appearance menu.

Answer (score 8):

At this time this is not possible due to bug [#1291359](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1291359/).

This issue is still present up to Ubuntu 16.04.

The most common thing to do at this moment is to show the default login screen/color.

You can do this by installing dconf Editor.
Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

*or click [dconf Editor](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-editor) [image: Install dconf Editor] to auto-open Software Center and click <kbd>Install</kbd> to install it.*

Now we must grant LightDM permissions to access dconf Editor.

- Gain root access, type your password (no visual feedback),and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
  `sudo -i`
- Allow user to create a connection to the X server for lightdm
  `xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm`
- Switch to user lightdm
  `su lightdm -s /bin/bash`
- Start dconf Editor
  `dconf-editor`

On dconf Editor, navigate to `com > canonical > unity-greeter` in the left pane.

- Disable (untick) the value for 'draw-user-backgrounds' on the right pane.
- While at it, you may want to disable 'draw-grid' (it disables the dotted grid layer).

Reboot to confirm changes.

```
sudo reboot
```

*Note: from now on LightDM has permission to access the X server, so every time you open dconf Editor, LightDM already has access.

To revoke this access, issue the command `xhost -SI:localuser:lightdm` as root.*

Comment: And what about using a different greeter? Could that work?

Comment: @Alfro I tried unity-greeter, lightdm-gtk-greeter, lightdm-kde-greeter but unfortunately they also do not offer any options to span the wallpaper on login screen.

Comment: Note: I tried your approach and got the error `dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/home/tvbox/.cache/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.`

Comment: @ElderGeek I updated the answer. I have forgotten to allow LightDM to access the X server. It should now work.

Comment: CLI method Error `dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line.` The GUI method works though.

Comment: @ElderGeek It needs more testing on my side and my current internet connection fails me. By the way thank you for feedback and tips. Care to have a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44108/chat-of-panagiotis-tabakis-and-elder-geek) with me for a question or two?

Comment: Updated the answer and removed the non-working terminal-only method as it gives errors as described in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. To save you some poking around, I've tried Variety, dconf-editor, nitrogen, and CompizConfig with no luck. The closest I could get was setting a particular wallpaper for just the lock screen with dconf-editor.

Strangely, if you install gnome-tweak-tool there *is* a setting under Desktop that allows you to choose a separate mode and image for the Background and Lock Screen - but while the Background settings here affect my desktop, my tests with the Lock Screen settings don't make any change. It may be a lead, however, if you want to try and finagle Unity into submitting to Gnome (assuming the tweak options haven't just been broken from the start).